# No data is getting into a table built over a stream from ksql binary, it get's there if I do the same with ksql prompt?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I'm trying to create a table over a stream using ksql binary. The table gets created and starts running but when I query it there is no data inside the table. When I create the same using ksql prompt the table gets created I'm also able to query the data.

PS: I am setting this property  SET 'auto.offset.reset'='earliest'; to query the data form beginning.

I tried both methods. It works when I create table using ksql prompt. Same command does not work when try to do the same with ksql binary.

```
sudo echo "CREATE TABLE movie_table AS SELECT title, count(*) AS appearance FROM test WHERE year > 1988 GROUP BY title;" | sh /home/binary/ksql http://devopsksql.default.svc.cluster.local:8088
```

```
ksql> CREATE TABLE movie_table AS SELECT title, count(*)
```

```
 Message
---------------------------
 Table created and running
---------------------------

ksql> select * from MOVIE_TABLE;
^CQuery terminated
```

Same when I run with ksql prompt open it works as is.

I am expecting a way to create a table and query it without using the ksql prompt.

Comment: which version of KSQL are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `SET 'auto.offset.reset'='earliest';` before your *`CREATE`* query.

If you want to interact with KSQL from a script I'd suggest using the REST API (e.g. via `curl`) than trying to pipe to the ksql binary.